# Voltage divider resistor value

Tags: voltage-divider

What happens if the difference between the resistance of two resistors is too large in a voltage divider? Let's say that I want to use a 1 megohm and a 2 ohms for my voltage divider.

Comment: That depends where it’s connected

Comment: I think hacktastical gave you a good answer. You gave us no real information to base a qualitative answer on. Voltag, Load, Frequency, etc all will enter into the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Too large', but too large for what purpose..

If you apply 100V to the 1M resistor and the 2 ohm resistor is grounded, you'll get about 200uV across the 2 ohm resistor and the source impedance will be about 2 ohms.

Easily measurable to fairly high accuracy.

One issue with having a high-ratio divider is the connections to the 2 ohm resistor may have significant resistance, even a few m\$\Omega\$ is significant if it's a precision circuit, so it may be better in some situations to divide down in two stages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feA1Jy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the second case, the output impedance is about 1K rather than 2 ohms but the sensitivity to connection resistances is reduced by about 500:1.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special. The divider equation still holds. In your example, Vout = Vin * (2 / (1000000 + 2). I suppose the large ratio makes the equation more sensitive to variations in the numerator - its influence in the denominator is swamped by 1M ohm value.

Answer (score 2):

> *Let's say i want to use 1 Mega ohms and 2 ohms for my voltage divider*

Odd things can happen dynamically if your expectations are to use that ratio of potential divider in (say) a high voltage power supply where it acts as a feedback node.

The 1 MΩ might have a few pF of capacitance across it. If it has say 10 pF (worst case), it will produce a high-pass shelving cut-off frequency of: -

$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi RC} = 15.9\text{ kHz}$$

Any noise or ripple that has a frequency above that will not be subject to the DC ratio of the two resistors and this could cause significant problems in a control loop. To counter this you'd want to put a capacitor across the 2 Ω resistor that balanced that problem out.

In other words you make it a potential divider that is usable from DC up to a frequency that is significantly higher than 15.9 kHz to ensure that ripple doesn't get magnified significantly and that the control loop stability is not compromised.

Ideally you'd pick a capacitance that is 500,000 times bigger than the 10 pF I mentioned earlier. This works out at 6 μF. In other words, 10 pF and 6 μF have a voltage reduction ratio that is identical to 1 MΩ and 2 Ω.